# selectors for action elements: class vs custom HTML5 attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A kinda of subjective issue I think. I have an action element and want to refer to it in the code for binding event I'm trying to choose between to ways of declaring such things:

1) the first option is more simple and straightforward in declaring and use:

```
<a class="play">Play</a>

('#menu .play').bind('click',...)
```

2) but the second option shows explicitly the purpose of the attribute

```
<a data-action="play">Play</a>

('#menu [data-action="play"]').bind('click',...)
```

Which should I choose (I'm not going to use selectors in CSS, only in JS code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using it for styles, I'd lean towards `data-action="play"` because it better describes the purpose (the action is play).
However, if you are planning on getting multiple elements like this and looping over them, I would either use `class="play"`, because then you're treating them like a class of the same kind of thing again.. or use **both**, *class* for getting them and *data-action* to verify, can't go wrong there.

Comment: I'd err on the side of always using a class where possible despite a possible lack of semantism, simply because it's ~20% faster than an attribute selector: http://jsperf.com/id-selector-vs-attribute-selector/5

Comment: I agree that class selectors are faster than attribute selectors (unless maybe if you have a lot of classes on the same tags), but if you don't have thousands of tags in #menu, and you don't want to find them too often, I believe semantism can be a big plus.